# Unit Test and IDistributedCache using azure redis

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I have a working implementation of Azure Redis and .Net Core 2 using code very similar to what's described in this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-redis-cache-on-your-net-core-application/)

My question is, how do you instantiate an instance of the cache from a unit test class?  I've looked through a number of resources and found nothing.

I need to be able to create an instance to instantiate a class such as

```
    public CacheManager(IDataManager dataservices, IDistributedCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _dataservices = dataservices;
    }
```

The code in startup.cs uses ConfigureServices

```
            //Configure Redis Cache
        var redisconnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
        services.AddDistributedRedisCache(o => { o.Configuration = redisconnection; });
```

Maybe I need to add a package to the unit test project?  How is this done?

Answer (score 23):

I have used the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.MemoryDistributedCache` class for unit testing. This is an in-memory implementation of `IDistributedCache`.

Here is a snippet of my unit testing code.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTestMethod()
        {
            var expectedData = new byte[] { 100, 200 };

            var opts = Options.Create<MemoryDistributedCacheOptions>(new MemoryDistributedCacheOptions());
            IDistributedCache cache1 = new MemoryDistributedCache(opts);
            cache1.Set("key1", expectedData);
            var cachedData = cache1.Get("key1");

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedData, cachedData);

           //Use the variable cache as an input to any class which expects IDistributedCache
        }
```

In my example, I am on .NET Core 3.1 and the relevant NUGET packages are

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" Version="3.1.4" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just mock the interfaces to behave as needed for the isolated unit test.

```
public void Test_CacheManager() {
    //Arrange
    IDataManager dataservices = new Mock<IDataManager>(); 
    IDistributedCache cache = new Mock<IDistributedCache>();
    var subject = new CacheManager(dataservices.Object, cache.Object);

    //Setup the mocks to behave as expected.

    //Act
    //...call the method under test

    //Assert
    //...assert the expected behavior
}
```

The above example uses Moq in order to demonstrate how to mock instances of the dependencies of the class under test.

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking library.

If you are connecting to an actual redis connection then this will no longer be a unit test but an integration test, which would require a completely different approach.

```
public void Test_CacheManager() {
    //Arrange

    IDataManager dataservices = new Mock<IDataManager>(); 
     //Setup the mocks to behave as expected.

    //Configure Redis Cache
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    var redisconnection = "...";
    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(o => { o.Configuration = redisconnection; });
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    IDistributedCache cache = provider.GetService<IDistributedCache>();

    var subject = new CacheManager(dataservices.Object, cache);

    //Act
    //...call the method under test

    //Assert
    //...assert the expected behavior
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to create the actual implementation that would access Azure Redis?

Comment: @user2503078 that would require checking the source code to see how they do it and then try to replicate it. otherwise you would need to go down the integration testing route which is completely different topic.

Comment: My bad, I am referring to what many would call an integration test.  The second part of the answer is the code I couldn't find.  Thanks

Comment: Where is this extension? services.AddDistributedRedisCache

Comment: @user2503078 You are probably missing a reference to the associated library and a using at the top of the test file. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.rediscacheservicecollectionextensions.adddistributedrediscache?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @user2503078 documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1):

This how i managed to do that in .net core 2.0 and 3.1.
You need to use MemoryDistributedCache. And pass it through your service constructor. Your service in a real word uses IDistributedCache by depedency injection. MemoryDistributedCache also implements IDistributedCache.

```
var mockedCacheSettings = new Mock<IOptions<CacheSettings>>();

        var options = new OptionsWrapper<MemoryDistributedCacheOptions>(new MemoryDistributedCacheOptions());
        _memoryDistributedCache = new MemoryDistributedCache(options);
        _distributedCacheService = new DistributedCacheService(_memoryDistributedCache, mockedCacheSettings.Object, NullLogger<DistributedCacheService>.Instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

i needed DistributedCache for test a service so i wrote these code:

```
private IDistributedCache BuildDistributedCash()
{
    var opt = Options.Create(new MemoryDistributedCacheOptions());
    return new MemoryDistributedCache(opt);
}

[Fact]
public async Task CheckStatusTest()
{
    var buildDistributedCash = BuildDistributedCash();
    var authService = new AuthService(buildDistributedCash);
    var userName = "test.z@gmail.com";

    bool result = await authService.CheckStatus(userName);

    Assert.True(result); 
}
```